# can i make a jquery ajax request in an ajax response?

Tags: jquery

I would like to make few ajax calls based on the response of my ajax call

something like this

```
$.post('test1.php', function(res) {

    var processid = res.processid;

    $.post('test2.php', id : processid, function (data){

        // do some stuff and make other ajax calls
    });

},'json')
```

Is this correct? i need to make additional requests based on the responses each request.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is correct.  The 2nd `POST` will run after the 1st completes.

Or, you can make a queue, using jQuery's [`$.queue`](http://api.jquery.com/queue) and [`$.dequeue`](http://api.jquery.com/dequeue), and using [`$.data`](http://api.jquery.com/data) to store the variable.  You could also use an AJAX Queue plugin (Google for them), I don't use any, so I can't suggest one.

```
//Add POST 1
$(document).queue('AJAX', function(next){
    $.post('test1.php', function(res){
        $(document).data('processid', res.processid); //We need to store this somewhere
        next(); //Call next queued function (if any)
    }, 'json');
});

//Add POST 2
$(document).queue('AJAX', function(next){
  $.post('test2.php', 'id='+$(document).data('processid'), function (data){
    next(); //Call next queued function (if any)
  });
});

// Start the queue
$(document).dequeue('AJAX');
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Is there any better way for doing this? or any library/plugin available that will queue my requests

Comment: @supa: There are plenty of plugins, just google "Ajax Queue".  I don't use any of them, so I can't suggest one.  I made an ajax queue, using jQuery's `$.queue` and `$.dequeue`.